# Screen not refreshing in React Native automatically

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

```
async componentDidMount () {         
        this._isMounted = true;
        await this.showPosts();
  }

  componentDidUpdate () {
        this.showPosts();   
  }

  showPosts = async () => {    
    try {    
    var userID = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userID');

    fetch(strings.baseUri+"getPostWithUserID", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
           Accept: 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ 
            "user_id": userID
        })
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {

        let jsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responseJson));

        if (jsonObj.status=="true") {

            this.setState({ 
                data: responseJson.data, 
                imageSrc: responseJson.data.imgSrc, 
            });

        } 
        else {
            if (this._isMounted) {
                this.setState({show: false});
            }
        }  

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
      }

  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }
```

`showPosts` is my function which fetches data and shows it into a Flatlist.

```
 <FlatList 
            data={this.state.data}
            keyExtractor={(index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={ ({item,index}) => this._renderItem(item,index) }
            extraData={[ this.state.checked, this.state.data ]}
 />
```

1. Now when I upload one post and go back to my home screen which calls `showPosts` and check it on my emulator by reloading the app again, it shows me the post.
2. And now, when I upload another post and go back to my home screen, I don't need to reload my app in emulator but my `componentDidUpdate` gets called and refreshes the screen automatically and shows me the new post.

My question is that why do I have to reload (reloading it by pressing R multiple times) my app again when there is zero post on home screen. I want my screen to be updated automatically when I upload the first post. The screen is getting updated automatically only where there are more than 1 post.

P.S. - I've also tried `onRefresh()` , didn't helped in my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong method. Component did update will be called after the update. You should use shouldComponentUpdate instead and return true/false there.

You can pass the prop while navigating to home screen like this:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("PathName", {option: "update"})
```

Then in Home screen catch it in the shouldComponentUpdate

```
 shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if(nextProps.navigation.state.params.option === "update") {
        this.showPosts()
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Or perhaps you should store your list of posts in state manager such as redux, and make this the source of data for your list. Then update the list in different screen, the list will be automatically updated on HomeScreen

Comment: can you please give me an example on how to use this in my case?

Comment: How do you upload post? You do it in the app?

Comment: yes. I've a tab from where i click a picture and then it navigates back to home screen and the home screen gets updated (if there is more than 1 post)

Comment: It gives me an error.  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'nextProps.navigation.state.params.option')

Comment: try 
if(nextProps.navigation.state.params) {
        if(nextProps.navigation.state.params.option === "update") {
        this.showPosts()
        return true
    }
    }

Comment: This doesn't seems to be the right answer. It's giving me a warning

Comment: What warning? Please be more specific

Comment: The warning is - "Home",shouldComponentUpdate(): Returned undefined instead of a boolean value. Make sure to return true or false.

Comment: And what part of it you are not understanding? You must return a boolean, true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Use `forceUpdate()`

please check this link : https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

Comment: I tried. Didn't work for me. I tried   `forceUpdate () {
   this.showPosts(); 
  }`